# Javascript in DotNetNuke 6.1.3

Tags: javascript, dotnetnuke

I am building a website in DNN, and I want to include Javascript in one of its HTML Modules.

I added the Javascript in footer/header (Settings > Advance Settings) but it didn't work. Then I tried adding the content by switching to basic editor and selecting RAW mode, but it's still not working.

Here is my Javascript. It is for tab browsing, to test whether Javascript is working or not I wrote a simple script in another HTML module, and it worked fine, but this script isn't running:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tabLinks = new Array();
var contentDivs = new Array();

function init() {

    var tabListItems = document.getElementById('tabs').childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < tabListItems.length; i++) {
        if (tabListItems[i].nodeName == "LI") {
            var tabLink = getFirstChildWithTagName(tabListItems[i], 'A');
            var id = getHash(tabLink.getAttribute('href'));
            tabLinks[id] = tabLink;
            contentDivs[id] = document.getElementById(id);
        }
    }

    var i = 0;

    for (var id in tabLinks) {
        tabLinks[id].onclick = showTab;
        tabLinks[id].onfocus = function() {
            this.blur()
        };
        if (i == 0) tabLinks[id].className = 'selected';
        i++;
    }

    var i = 0;

    for (var id in contentDivs) {
        if (i != 0) contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent hide';
        i++;
    }
}

function showTab() {
    var selectedId = getHash(this.getAttribute('href'));

    for (var id in contentDivs) {
        if (id == selectedId) {
            tabLinks[id].className = 'selected';
            contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent';
        } else {
            tabLinks[id].className = '';
            contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent hide';
        }
    }

    return false;
}

function getFirstChildWithTagName(element, tagName) {
    for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++) {
        if (element.childNodes[i].nodeName == tagName) return element.childNodes[i];
    }
}

function getHash(url) {
    var hashPos = url.lastIndexOf('#');
    return url.substring(hashPos + 1);
}​
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There shouldn't be any problem with adding JavaScript to the header/footer.  When you say it didn't work, did you check the source of the page, or did the behavior just not work?  Did you check for JavaScript errors in your browser's console?

So far as adding JavaScript via the Basic/Raw view of the rich text editor, DNN strips JavaScript from the text editor by default.  You can turn that off via the HTML Editor Manager (under Host).